# Achieving Netbeans-style line moving and duplicating in VIM

Tags: vim, netbeans

In Netbeans, Ctrl-Shift-Up/Down duplicates the current line or selection and Alt+Shift+Up/Down/Left/Right moves the current line or selection.  How can this be achieved in VIM 7?

So far, I'm able to get Alt+Shift+Up/Down working using these mappings:

```
:nmap <A-S-up> :m .-2<Enter>
:imap <A-S-up> <Esc>:m .-2<Enter>gi
:vmap <A-S-up> :m .-2<Enter>gv

:nmap <A-S-down> :m .+1<Enter>
:imap <A-S-down> <Esc>:m +1<Enter>gi
:vmap <A-S-down> :m '>+1<Enter>gv
```

I'm still strugging with:

1. Having Alt+Shift+j/k work like Alt+Shift+Up/Down.  Simply changing "up" to "k" isn't working.
2. Ctrl-Shift-Up/Down mappings aren't working.  Is this an unmappable sequence?
3. To map both Alt+Shift+up and Alt+Shift+k to the same command, is there a better way than duplicating the map command to another line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of this works in VIM but it all works in GVIM.

```
" Alt+Shift+Up/k moves content up
:nmap <M-S-Up> :m .-2<Enter>
:nmap <M-S-k> <M-S-Up>
:imap <M-S-Up> <Esc>:m .-2<Enter>gi
:imap <M-S-k> <M-S-Up>
:vmap <M-S-Up> :m .-2<Enter>gv
:vmap <M-S-k> <M-S-Up>

" Alt+Shift+Down/j moves content down
:nmap <M-S-Down> :m .+1<Enter>
:nmap <M-S-j> <M-S-Down>
:imap <M-S-Down> <Esc>:m .+1<Enter>gi
:imap <M-S-j> <M-S-Down>
:vmap <M-S-Down> :m '>+1<Enter>gv
:vmap <M-S-j> <M-S-Down>

" Ctrl+Shift+Up/k copies content up
:nmap <C-S-Up> :co .-1<Enter>
:nmap <C-S-k> <C-S-Up>
:imap <C-S-Up> <Esc>:co .<Enter>gi
:imap <C-S-k> <C-S-Up>
:vmap <C-S-Up> :co '><Enter>gv
:vmap <C-S-k> <C-S-Up>

" Ctrl+Shift+Down/j copies content down
:nmap <C-S-Down> :co .<Enter>
:nmap <C-S-j> <C-S-Down>
:imap <C-S-Down> <Esc>:co .<Enter>gi<Down>
:imap <C-S-j> <C-S-Down>
:vmap <C-S-Down> :co .-1<Enter>gv
:imap <C-S-j> <C-S-Down>

" Alt+Shift+Left/h shifts content left 
:nmap <M-S-Left> <<
:nmap <M-S-h> <M-S-Left>
:imap <M-S-Left> ^D
:imap <M-S-h> <M-S-Left>
:vmap <M-S-Left> <gv
:vmap <M-S-h> <M-S-Left>

" Alt+Shift+Right/l shifts content right
:nmap <M-S-Right> >>
:nmap <M-S-l> <M-S-Right>
:imap <M-S-Right> ^T
:imap <M-S-l> <M-S-Right>
:vmap <M-S-Right> >gv
:vmap <M-S-l> <M-S-Right>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing out the key sequence, press Ctrl-V (or Ctrl-Q on Windows) and then your key sequence.

In other words, instead of typing this:

<kbd><</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>

Type this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>

I don't really understand why, but for some reason vim doesn't translate all key combinations in the way that you think it would.  For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> shows up as `Ë` for me, but the key mapping still works.  And <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> translates to `<M-S-Up>` rather than `<A-S-Up>`.

As to your third question, map one key combination to the other.

```
:nmap <A-S-up> :m .-2<Enter>
:nmap Ë <A-S-up>
```

(Keep in mind that `Ë` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, at least on my machine.)